# Running a .bat file from another server in PHP

Tags: php, batch-file

I have a file - `file.bat` - which is located on a different server than our web site.  I'd like to be able to run this file within our site; however, I'm not too familiar with .bat files, usage, etc. and was curious if anyone knows how I may be able to execute this from a different server?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to run this program using PHP.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that it would need to be on a different server? It will cause a lot of security issues if not done right plus you would be hard pushed to find a host that allows the shell_exec() function

Comment: Problem is we have our web hosting through AT&T, but we also have our own internal servers which holds the file.  Basically here's what were hoping to do: we use FilePro (awful) interally, and we'd like our customers to be able to go onto our website (hosted by ATT) and check stock of a particular item.  Now we have the batch file working correctly on our servers, but I do not know how to access the file from our hosted servers.

Comment: if you are checking stock then why not use a database and have the publicly facing server connect to your local database rather then through files and .bat's?

Comment: You would think that would be the ideal solution; however, our internal DBMS (FilePro) does not allow for remote connections to external databases at the moment, which is a crippling limitation, which is why this batch script was made up to pull the info we're looking for and stores it on our web server.  Problem is, I can't execute the batch script from our site.

Comment: You will want to investigate [`ssh2_exec()`](http://php.net/ssh2_exec) and setting up your internal system to support that. (Be sure to filter the input to your batch file anyway, even if you manage the authorization safely and can trust the AT&T server setup.)

Comment: Why don't you simply replace the batch file by a PHP script?

Comment: I didn't write the batch file, and not sure if it would be possible to execute PHP within our internal system (FilePro)

Comment: "filePro support in PHP is not enabled by default. To enable the bundled read-only filePro support you need to use the--enable-filepro configuration option when compiling PHP." - PHP.net (the only problem is I cannot recompile our PHP since it is on an ATT hosted server.

Answer (score 0):

`.bat` or batch files are scripts. They need an interpreter to run, normally integrated into the shell/commandline.

If you want to execute such a shell-script from remote, you need a remote-shell. You simply connect to the shell from remote and then you execute the shell-script in that shell.

So the other system that has the `.bat` file in question must offer a remote shell you can connect to via PHP and then you're ready to go.

However even if technically possible this does not mean that it makes sense. What does the `.bat` file do?

Comment: Just checks stock of a particular item, and places the output in a txt file on our web server, which I can then use to give to the web user. --- Assuming our internal server does allow for a remote shell connection, how would I be able to accomplish this and execute in PHP?

Comment: You can access a remote shell either via HTTP making use of the CGI interface (if the other server has a webserver, place a PHP script in there that uses [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to execute the `.bat` file - this is most probably the easiest), or open a [SSH connection from within PHP to the remote server](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) (SSH is a standard protocol for remote shells).

Comment: For example: $output = shell_exec(/cgi-bin/file.bat $userInput)?  Like I said, it only check inventory on our system, and needs to accept a single user input (part number).

Comment: If something like that would work, I'd be able to write that output to a txt file and ftp it up to our web server, where I'd be able to pull it down and show the user.

Comment: Windows systems will hardly have UNIX paths, so mabye more like: `shell_exec("c:\file.bat {$userInput}");`. The same PHP script could deal with the output as well and return it to STDOUT which would make it accessible remotely directly. My remote access will be shutdown soon as well, I'm going offline. cu.

Comment: You can execute `.bat` files on unix? Well then fine, good luck!